# Fragment within WindowManager in android

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-windowmanager

I am developing chat bubble like Messenger but i want to create container layout with fragment. I want to open container layout on click of chat bubble and container layout also contain fragment.

I don't how i use fragment in WindowManager, i searching too much but can't find any solution.

**WindowManager**

```
mFloatingView = LayoutInflater.from(bubblesService.getBaseContext()).inflate(R.layout.bubble_content_layout, null);

        final WindowManager.LayoutParams params = new WindowManager.LayoutParams(
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_PHONE,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE,
                PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);

        params.gravity = Gravity.TOP | Gravity.LEFT; 
        BubbleLayout bb = getBubble().get(0);
        params.x = bb.getDisplaySize();
        params.y = 100;

        mContentWindowManager = (WindowManager) bubblesService.getBaseContext().getSystemService(bubblesService.getBaseContext().WINDOW_SERVICE);
        mContentWindowManager.addView(mFloatingView, params);
```

**Containlayout**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/chat_away"
    android:clipChildren="false"
    android:clipToPadding="false">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Working..." />

    <fragment
        class="com.txusballesteros.bubbles.app.HomeFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: You can't, AFAIK. Maybe with some really ugly, unreliable hack. Why do you need a `Fragment` for that anyway?

Comment: I am developing file manager so there too many fragment